# What are the rules for JNI local references returned to a program that embeds a Java VM?

Tags: java, c, memory-management, java-native-interface

The [JNI docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#referencing_java_objects) describe the rules for resource management of objects returned from the JNI. Here's a quote that gives a good overview:

> The JNI divides object references used by the native code into two
>   categories: local and global references. Local references are valid
>   for the duration of a native method call, and are automatically freed
>   after the native method returns. Global references remain valid until
>   they are explicitly freed.
>
> Objects are passed to native methods as local references. All Java
>   objects returned by JNI functions are local references. The JNI allows
>   the programmer to create global references from local references. JNI
>   functions that expect Java objects accept both global and local
>   references. A native method may return a local or global reference to
>   the VM as its result.

This documentation is obviously geared towards using the JNI to implement methods in native code but the JNI can also be used for embedding. What are the rules for embedding? When the 'native method call' that a JNI function returns to is an enclosing program which is embedding a VM, the 'native method call', i.e. the program, will never return to the VM. What are the rules in that case? Can a program that embeds the JNI tell the JNI that it can free a previously returned object?

**Edit:**

Here's an example of code where I'm not sure how to handle an object returned from the JNI based on the docs. `TestKlass.java` defines a simple Java class. `run.c` starts an embedded Java VM and loads the `TestKlass` class using the JNI and then runs the `TestKlass` constructor to get a `jobject` instance of `TestKlass`. What are the resource management rules for the returned `jobject`? When will the Java VM assume that it can safely release the object?

The code starts the Java VM with `Xcheck:jni` and the VM does not print any errors, but that doesn't guarantee that no errors exist in this code. If there are errors in this example, how could I have detected them?

TestKlass.java

```
public class TestKlass {
    public TestKlass() {
                System.out.println("Java: TestKlass::TestKlass()");
    }
}
```

run.c

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

JNIEnv* create_vm(JavaVM** jvm)
{
    JNIEnv* env;
    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;

    // For this example, TestKlass.java and run.c are assumed to live in and
    //     be compiled in the same directory, so '.' is added to the Java
    //     path.
    char opts0[] = "-Djava.class.path=.";
    char opts1[] = "-Xcheck:jni";
    JavaVMOption opts[2];
    opts[0].optionString = opts0;
    opts[1].optionString = opts1;

    vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
    vm_args.nOptions = 2;
    vm_args.options = opts;
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = 0;

    jint r = JNI_CreateJavaVM(jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
    if (r < 0 || !env) {
        printf("Unable to Launch JVM %d\n", r);
        abort();
    }
    printf("Launched JVM! :)\n");

    return env;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    JavaVM *jvm;
    JNIEnv *env;
    env = create_vm(&jvm);
    if(env == NULL)
        return 1;

    jclass cls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "TestKlass");
    jmethodID mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "<init>", "()V");
    jobject jobj = (*env)->NewObject(env, cls, mid);

    // (Assume that arbitrary JNI calls will be made after this point, the
    //     program will persist for a long time, and returned Java objects may
    //     be large.)
    // What are the rules for negotiating management of jobj with the Java VM?
    // Does the answer change if the object was returned from a
    //     non-constructor function?
    // Is there any way to use the JNI to tell the Java VM either that jobj
    //     can be freed here or that it must not be freed here?
    // Would DeleteLocalRef() be helpful here?

    // ...

    (*jvm)->DestroyJavaVM(jvm);
}
```

output

```
Launched JVM! :)
Java: TestKlass::TestKlass()
```

I know C but I haven't used Java in a long time. I'm mostly working from the JNI docs. If I'm missing something obvious, *please* point it out in an answer or comment.

Comment: What? I don't understand what you are asking.. A function in JNI can only return LOCAL references IF that the reference is captured by a Java program interacting with it (IE: Garbage Collection). Otherwise the local reference dies when the function ends. Thus the function must make the reference global and return that in order for another C function to use it, then it must be freed after.

Comment: @Brandon I'll try to clarify in words first but I can add an example. A C program embeds a Java VM, i.e. calls `JNI_CreateJavaVM()`. It calls a JNI function that returns a Java object. Since the C program is above the VM in the native call stack, it will never return to the VM. Is there any way for the C program to tell Java that it can free the returned object? The C program could create a global reference but there will still be a local reference. There's no enclosing Java function in this case. (I don't regularly use Java so it could be me that is confused here. Please just say so.)

Comment: If you create a JVM you must destroy it yourself. If you allocate a Java object within that VM, the vm can free it depending on the type of object. Otherwise you must free it yourself (ie: strings -- you call "ReleaseStringUTFChars").

Comment: @Brandon Check the example I added. The JVM is manually destroyed. A Java object is created here but it seems like the VM has no chance to free it  during the life of the program since the VM never regains control flow and there's no call that manually tells the VM that it may free the object. If there is an error in this code, how could I have found it? Please ask for clarification if needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you say, you are not in a `native` method so there will be no cleaning up upon "return". Your question is about cleaning well before return.

To free a [local reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#local_references), you have two choices:

- `DeleteLocalRef` for one reference.
- `PushLocalFrame`/`PopLocalFrame` for a group of references.

(I suspect `PushLocalFrame`/`PopLocalFrame` is how the clean up of a `native` method is done.)

**Example:**

TestKlass.java

```
public class TestKlass {
    public TestKlass() {
        System.out.println("Java: TestKlass::TestKlass()");
    }

    public void finalize() {
        System.out.println("Java: TestKlass::finalize()");
    }

    public static void force_gc() {
        System.out.println("Java: TestKlass::force_gc()");

        System.gc();
        System.runFinalization();
    }
}
```

run.c

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

JNIEnv* create_vm(JavaVM** jvm)
{
    JNIEnv* env;
    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;

   // For this example, TestKlass.java and run.c are assumed to live in and
    //     be compiled the same directory, so '.' is added to the Java path.
    char opts0[] = "-Djava.class.path=.";
    char opts1[] = "-Xcheck:jni";
    JavaVMOption opts[2];
    opts[0].optionString = opts0;
    opts[1].optionString = opts1;

    vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
    vm_args.nOptions = 2;
    vm_args.options = opts;
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = 0;

    jint r = JNI_CreateJavaVM(jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
    if (r < 0 || !env) {
        printf("Unable to Launch JVM %d\n", r);
        abort();
    }
    printf("Launched JVM! :)\n");

    return env;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    JavaVM *jvm;
    JNIEnv *env;
    env = create_vm(&jvm);
    if(env == NULL)
        return 1;

    jclass cls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "TestKlass");
    jmethodID mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "<init>", "()V");
    jobject jobj = (*env)->NewObject(env, cls, mid);

    (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, jobj);
    jmethodID mid2 = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, cls, "force_gc", "()V");
    (*env)->CallStaticVoidMethod(env, cls, mid2);

    (*jvm)->DestroyJavaVM(jvm);
}
```

output

```
Launched JVM! :)
Java: TestKlass::TestKlass()
Java: TestKlass::force_gc()
Java: TestKlass::finalize()
```

Removing either the call to `DeleteLocalRef()` or the call to `force_gc()` prevents `finalize()` from running.

Comment: Can you cite any documentation or give example code showing that `DeleteLocalRef` allows the Java VM to clean up objects returned to an embedding program? `DeleteLocalRef` doesn't cause `finalize()` to run but then again, I don't believe `finalize()` is ever *required* to run.

Comment: If there's some way to query the garbage collector, that could be used to prove this answer correct.

Comment: @Praxeolitic Thanks for the example. (I would upvote your edit if that was possible.)

Comment: @TomBlodget I have a few questions if I may: 1. Why delete references if we are exiting from main function already? 2. What if we have a jvm process that is calling native methods - do we need to clear local references before returning from function? They should be automatically freed on function exit, right? 3. Do we only need to clear object references or also class / methodID / fieldID?

Answer (score 0):

You must turn your `jobj` into a `GlobalRef` as soon as you acquire it, and call `DeleteGlobalRef()` when you're finished with it.

Comment: This is a good conservative suggestion for what *should* be done but in this case I want to know what exactly *must* be done.

Comment: @Praxeolitic OK so I used the wrong word. You *must* do this.

Comment: I was emphasizing 'must' to try to say that I'm looking for an explanation of the JNI rules -- the 'musts and must nots'. When is the Java VM allowed to cleanup `jobj` if it remains a local reference?

Comment: @Praxeolitic Any time it likes.

Answer (score 0):

I did some investigation on this while writing a Java plugin for Unity. I didn't find the JVM releasing any local references without a call to either `deleteLocalRef` or `popLocalFrame`, making them effectively global references, although they probably shouldn't be used that way.

Here's my test, in which I manually checked the printed reference table outputs from Logcat on a Pixel 5.

```
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;
using UnityEngine;

/// <summary>
/// Tests various JNI behaviors.
/// </summary>
public class JniTest
{
    [Test]
    public void TestLocalReference()
    {
        CreateLocalReference(10000000);
        DumpReferenceTables();
    }
  
    [Test]
    public void TestGlobalReference()
    {
        CreateGlobalReference(10000000);
        DumpReferenceTables();
    }
  
    private void CreateLocalReference(int count)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            AndroidJNI.NewString(i.ToString());
        }
    }
  
    private void CreateGlobalReference(int count)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            IntPtr local = AndroidJNI.NewString(i.ToString());
            AndroidJNI.NewGlobalRef(local);
            AndroidJNI.DeleteLocalRef(local);
        }
    }
  
    private void DumpReferenceTables()
    {
        IntPtr debugClass = AndroidJNI.FindClass("android/os/Debug");
        IntPtr methodId = AndroidJNI.GetStaticMethodID(debugClass, "dumpReferenceTables", "()V");
        AndroidJNI.CallStaticVoidMethod(debugClass, methodId, null);
    }
}
```

Interestingly, Unity on Android has a different max count than the usually advertised 512 local and 65536 global. I get the following crash logs:

```
JNI ERROR (app bug): global reference table overflow (max=51200)global reference table dump:
    runtime.cc:677]   Last 10 entries (of 51200):
    runtime.cc:677]     51199: 0x12fc8f10 java.lang.String "50695"
    runtime.cc:677]     51198: 0x12fc8ef8 java.lang.String "50694"
    runtime.cc:677]     51197: 0x12fc8ee0 java.lang.String "50693"
    runtime.cc:677]     51196: 0x12fc8ec8 java.lang.String "50692"
    runtime.cc:677]     51195: 0x12fc8eb0 java.lang.String "50691"
    runtime.cc:677]     51194: 0x12fc8e98 java.lang.String "50690"
    runtime.cc:677]     51193: 0x12fc8e80 java.lang.String "50689"
    runtime.cc:677]     51192: 0x12fc8e68 java.lang.String "50688"
    runtime.cc:677]     51191: 0x12fc8e50 java.lang.String "50687"
    runtime.cc:677]     51190: 0x12fc8e38 java.lang.String "50686"
...
```

And a similar yet surprising stack for local references:

```
JNI ERROR (app bug): local reference table overflow (max=8388608)
...
```

The limits might be different for other phones/setups, but the lesson is to always clean up local references when running stuff from native code.

I also tested the performance tradeoff of using delete vs pop, and found delete faster when cleaning up 2+ refs. Here's the results of running 1 million times of creating then deleting.

```
Refs/call | Push/Pop | DeleteLocalRef | Diff
0             474 ms          1078 ms    56%
1            5924 ms          6590 ms    10%
2           14986 ms         10716 ms   -40%
3           22581 ms         14618 ms   -54%
4           30045 ms         18418 ms   -63%
```

Here's the test's source code:

```
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;
using UnityEngine;

public class JniTest
{
    [Test]
    public void TestPerformance()
    {
        var watch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        int iterations = 1000000;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            watch.Start();
            MethodCallFrame(i, iterations);
            watch.Stop();
            long frameMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            
            watch.Restart();
            MethodCallNoFrame(i, iterations);
            watch.Stop();
            long noFrameMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            Debug.Log($"Test: {frameMs}, {noFrameMs}, {1 - (double)frameMs / noFrameMs}");
        }
    }

    private void MethodCallFrame(int args, int iterations)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            AndroidJNI.PushLocalFrame(0);
            for (int j = 0; j < args; j++)
            {
                AndroidJNI.NewString(j.ToString());
            }
            AndroidJNI.PopLocalFrame(IntPtr.Zero);
        }
    }
  
    private void MethodCallNoFrame(int argCount, int iterations)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            IntPtr[] args = new IntPtr[argCount];
            for (int j = 0; j < argCount; j++)
            {
                args[j] = AndroidJNI.NewString(j.ToString());
            }
            
            foreach (IntPtr ptr in args)
            {
                AndroidJNI.DeleteLocalRef(ptr);
            }
        }
    }
}
```